# Linear map and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a linear map from $\mathcal{V}$ to $\mathcal{V}$ (endomorphism, $A \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{V})$), with the following properties:

$\exists \space \space e \in \mathcal{V}$ and $n \ge 2$ such that $A^{n-1}e \not= 0$ and $A^ne = 0$.

I need to show that the vectors $e, Ae, A^2e, ..., A^{n-1}e$ are linearly independent. I guess I need to use linear map properties such as $A(0) = 0$, $A(u+v) = A(u) + A(v)$ and $A(\lambda u) = \lambda A(u)$, but I can't figure out how to do it. It seems easy, though. Please excuse my possible notation and terminology mistakes: English is not my native language, and a lot of the time I find it hard to translate mathematical terms from my language.

Comment: Do you mean $A^{n-1}e\neq 0$, $A^ne=0$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Missed it.

Comment: Suppose there is a non trivial linar combination. Then muliply with $A^k$ with a suitable $k$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: You mean: Say there is a solution $(a_0, a_1, ..., a_{n-1})$, with $a_k \not=0$, for which $a_0e+a_1Ae+...+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}e=0$. I then take $A^{n-1}$ from both sides to show that $a_0 = 0$, since $a_1A^n = 0, a_2A^{n+1} = 0, ..., a_{n-1}A^{2n-2}=0$. Then, knowing that $a_0=0$, that means that $a_1Ae+...+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}e=0$, and now I take $A^{n-2}$ from both sides to show that $a_1=0$, and so one until I show that $a_{n-1}=0$. Is this correct? It seems correct to me, and obvious right now, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution Domenico Vuono meant.

Comment: Yes. I saw his explanation right after I figured what I said in the comment. Thanks to both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$a_1e+a_2Ae+a_3A^2e+ ...+a_nA^{n-1}e=0$$ is a linear combination then $$A(a_1e+a_2Ae+a_3A^2e+ ...+a_nA^{n-1}e)=0$$ and....

Comment: I tried something similar, but I don't know how to finish the demonstration.

Comment: instead of multiplying by A, try multuplying by $A^{n-1}$. Then $a_1=0$. Then return to the beginning and multiply by $A^{n-2}$ etc.

Comment: Apply $A$ in the linear combination $n-1$ times and find that $a_1=0$ then if $a_1=0$ apply $A$ in the linear combination $n-2$ times and find $a_2=0$

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out. It seems quite obvious and easy now. I didn't get it at first because you applied $A$ only once, and I haven't thought about applying it $n-1$ times.